# Removing current line of a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I'm facing something that looks easy, but can't find the answer :

The goal of this function is to remove all the line that contains 3 commas ',' :

```
while read line; do                                                                                                    
        COUNT=$(echo $line | grep -o "\," | wc -)
        if [ $COUNT -ne 3 ]; then
               remove line
        fi
done < tmp.txt
```

I dont find how to remove current line, can you help me ?

I extract this `tmp.txt` from a larger with `grep`, if it was in a variable instead of a `tmp.txt` will it be the same ?

```
while read line; do
COUNT=$(echo $line | grep -o "\," | wc -)
       COUNT=$(echo $line | grep -o "\," | wc -)
        if [ $COUNT -ne 3 ]; then
               remove line
        fi
done <<< "$toto"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed` command only solution.

```
sed  '/^\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*$/d' infile
```

- Delete all those line which character comma `,` occurred exactly 3 times.

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NF!=4' infile
```

---

Or both read from a variable.

```
sed  '/^\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*$/d' <<<"$variable"
awk -F, 'NF!=4' <<<"$variable"
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple **awk** solution

```
awk 'gsub(/,/,",")!=3' file
```

`gsub` replaces the pattern with the specified string and it returns the number of substitutions/replacements made.

We are replacing `,` with `,` here and thus `gsub` will return us the number of `,` in the string.

**Example :**

**Input file**

```
hello this line has 1 ,
This line, has, 3 ,
This line, has, 4 , commas , Thanks
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'gsub(/,/,",")!=3' file
hello this line has 1 ,
This line, has, 4 , commas , Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it in the other way :

```
while read line; do                                                                                                    
        COUNT=$(echo $line | grep -o "\," | wc -)
        if [ $COUNT -eq 3 ]; then
               echo $line >> $tempofile
        fi
done < tmp.txt
```

If the line is matched, keep it, otherwise get to next line.

Answer (score -1):

This simple command can remove all the lines that contains 3

`$ awk '!/3/' file_name`

Comment: Not `3` itself, character comma `,` and when it's occurred 3times in a line.